# How I can change resize my list icon in HTML file

Tags: html, css

```css
#download_btn_1 {
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    background: #5cb85c;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#d-i_1 {
    list-style-image: url(here the link);
}
```

```html
<button id="download_btn_1"><li id="d-i_1">Button</li></button>
```

I can't resize list icons in buttons. Because I'm trying to make a download button with an icon. How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Change the size of the bullet (`•`)?

Comment: i dont know why You are using list inside the button

Comment: You could include the icon as a pseudo-element or as an element inside the button, e.g. `<button><span class="icon"></span>Button Text</button>`. If you just want a bigger bullet and not a custom icon, you could even just include that in the HTML: `<button>&#x25cf; Button</button>`

Comment: You can't have a `<li>` element inside a `<button>`. The `<li>` has to go inside a `<ul>` or `<ol>` element. Structurally invalid HTML only serves to produce unpredictable and surprising behaviour in browsers.

Answer (score -2):

```
#icon {
  list-style-image: url(../images/...);
  width: some width;
  height: some height;
}
```

Comment: #download_btn_1 {
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    background: #5cb85c;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}